# Convert double to string and remove euro sign currency

Tags: java

I am trying to format double values to currency and then remove the euro sign but my application crashed. can someone tell me where am wrong please?

```
public class Formatting {

    public static String replaceString(String text){

        NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        String moneyString = formatter.format(text);
        System.out.println("epargne: "+moneyString);

        return text.replaceAll("£", "");

    }

    public static String convert(double x){
        return replaceString(Double.toString(x));

    }

}
```

i called it as follows in class y

double x = a + b + c;

System.out.println(Formatting.convert(x));

Comment: suppose i have 1000.009 i convert it to 1,000.01 without the currency sign in front

Comment: Your code uses GBP '£', not EUR '€'.  Was that what you intended?

Comment: But you said your application crashes. Where do it crashes? What is the output?

Comment: i want to get rid of this symbol dear

Comment: The crash description is on the console and is called "exception", what do you read on the console?

Comment: What's the point of using a currency formatter if you don't want the currency?

Comment: try calling replaceAll using the unicode of the currency sign that you expect.
e.g for euro currency sign
text.replaceAll("\u20AC", "");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`format` accepts a double, no need to convert that value to a String. `replaceAll` requires a *regexp*, you can just simply use `replace` which requires a single char.

```
public static String replaceString(double value){
    NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    String currencySymbol = formatter.getCurrency().getSymbol();
    String moneyString = formatter.format(value);
    return moneyString.replace(currencySymbol, "");
}

public static String convert(double x){
    return replaceString(x);
}
```

Comment: Will +1 if you remove the hard coded currency symbol and use the proper value in its place.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't want to get currency returned, you could simply use `DecimalFormat` which will also give you rounding to 2 decimal places (from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878614/convert-double-to-string-and-remove-euro-sign-currency#comment19115418_13878614)):

```
public static String replaceString(double number) {    
   NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
   return formatter.format(number);
}
```